# how to fetch arraylist from jsp to action class in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I am displaying data to my JSP using iterator

```
<s:form action="report" name="excel" method="post">     
    <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <td >Employee Name</td>
                                <td>Status</td>
                                <td >Start Date</td>
                                <td >Due Date</td>
                                <td>Supervisor</td>
                                </tr>
<s:iterator value="EmployeeDetails"  status="stat" var="p1"  >

                                <tr><td ><s:property value="employee_name" /> <br></td>
                                    <td ><s:property value="status" /><br></td>             
                                    <td ><s:property value="start_date" /><br></td>
                                    <td ><s:property value="end_date" /><br></td>
                                    <td ><s:property value="supervisor" /> <br></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </s:iterator>
</table>
                        <s:hidden name="EmployeeDetail" value="%{EmployeeDetails}" />
<p><s:url action="report.action" var="urlTag" ><s:param name="parameter">Excel</s:param></s:url>
<a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />">Excel</a></s:form>
```

here EmployeeDetails is the arraylist which i fetched from action class.
now I want to fetch the same arraylist into report action class when user click on hyperlink excel.

I wrote getter setter method in the action class also tried to pass it using hidden variable but size is coming zero for the arraylist everytime.

```
public ArrayList<Report> EmployeeDetails = new ArrayList<Report>();
    public ArrayList<Report> EmployeeDetail = new ArrayList<Report>();
public ArrayList<Report> getEmployeeDetails() {
        return EmployeeDetails;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDetails(ArrayList<Report> employeeDetails) {
        EmployeeDetails = employeeDetails;
    }
    public ArrayList<Report> getEmployeeDetail() {
        return EmployeeDetail;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDetail(ArrayList<Report> employeeDetail) {
        EmployeeDetail = employeeDetail;
    }
```

I dont know what i am doing wrong here. Please help.
Is there any other way to fetch the arraylist from JSP?

Comment: Use IteratorStatus, dot and square brackets notations as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27902541/1654265 . Also start your variable names with a lowercase character

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Andrea . I tried to fetch using status of the iterator. And it worked.
But I set the arraylist in session and used it afterwards. I found it easier for my problem.